# SwiftUI Custom View does not update after @ObservedObject model changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have created a custom view which displays content depending on whether the passed argument is `nil` or not. The issue I'm facing is that the view is not updaating / invalidating when the optionalData changes. The optionalData is stored within my model.

```
struct MyUpdatingView {
    var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        if model.optionalData == nil { 
             ProgressView()
        } else {
             OptionalDataView(model.optionalData!)
        }
    }

}
```

Model:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {

    @Published var optionalData: OptionalData

    init (){
        loadOptionalDataAsync()
    }
}
```

The problem I face is that the view is not updating when the optional data is loaded, in my main view. The interesting thing, however, is that I can add a `Text(model.optionalData.debugDescription)` view which does appear to update when the data is loaded.

Any ideas! What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At least your `model` should be ObservedObject

```
struct MyUpdatingView {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model     // << here !!
    ...
```

also make sure you update `optionalData` on `DispatchQueue.main` after `loadOptionalDataAsync` finished.